# Libgdx / Scene2D Scaling not working

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, scale, scene2d

im currently developing a little duengon crawler and i wanna try to implement a healthbar using Scene2D. But theres a problem ... when i try to set the size of the progressbar its ever and ever the same size, doesnt matter if i do :

```
healthBar.setWidth(1f);
healthBar.setHeight(0.25f);

or

healthBar.setWidth(100);
healthBar.setHeight(25);
```

What im doing wrong ?? Heres how i created the stage ^^

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(0,0);
camera.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/Box2dVars.UNIT,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/Box2dVars.UNIT);
camera.zoom = (float) 0.75;

port = new ExtendViewport(camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight, camera);

stage = new Stage(port);
```

I also act and draw the stage every tick in the render method. Heres how i create the ProgressBar :

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("Scene2D-Skins/uiskin.json"));

healthBar = new ProgressBar(0, 100, 0.5f, false, skin, "default");

healthBar.setWidth(1f);
healthBar.setHeight(0.25f);
healthBar.setPosition(this.getPosition().x, this.getPosition().y);

this.gameScreen.stage.addActor(healthBar);
```

Did you see a mistake ?? What did i forgot ? :/ I would be happy about some help !

Comment: maybe you're setting the size somewhere else that overwrites wherever else you try to change the width, put a sysout for the healthbar size when it's drawn so you can see if it's actually what you expect.

Comment: Thats weierd, it prints out 100 for width and 25 for height. Even if i Set other values There... Im searching for the error now But cant finden anything

Comment: so you're saying you setWidth to x and in the very next line it shows width = something else?